# jQuery UI droppable, draggable, resizeable and snap to grid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, resizable

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div class="columns"></div>
    <div class="columns"></div>
    <div class="columns"></div>
    ...
</div>
<div id="assets">
    <div class="assets" id="asset1"></div>
    <div class="assets" id="asset2"></div>
    ...
</div>
```

and I want to make each asset droppable, draggable, resizable and snapping to each column that will be positioned underneath the assets. The jQuery UI draggable doesn't have snap to grid out of the box so I'm trying to adapt it to suit my needs, however even the snap of resizable only snaps to grid of pixel values (as far as I know anyway). Is there a way I could use

$(".assets").resizeable({ grid: $(".columns") }); ?

I've tried that and it doesn't work. I've also found this: https://github.com/polomoshnov/jQuery-UI-Resizable-Snap-extension

but it doesn't seems to work whit two different elements (one for the grid and other for the draggable).

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Thanks